# What's the difference between using RAW or JPG with After Effects?

Tags: lightroom, raw, jpeg, timelapse

I am making some timelapse videos. And I have around 1500 photos in RAW format. I did some adjustoments in Lightroom and then imported these RAW files to After Effects. But After Effects processed them very slowly, because they are RAW.

If I export RAW to JPG in Lightroom and then export them into After Effects - how big an impact will it make on image quality?  Will there be a big difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't make very much difference, because After Effects is likely doing the same thing you'd do in batch conversion in the first place, just as it goes along. I don't think it has any option to do this adaptively as it goes, with different RAW processing for each frame.

Still, using RAW probably avoids one extra recompression, but the *video* compression for the timelapse is going to be far stronger in any case. If you pick a high-quality JPEG export setting, I doubt you'll be able to detect a difference.

Comment: Yes, After Effect uses xmp metadata files. And it they are missed, then it opens Camera Raw and create them. You confirmed my thoughts about little difference. Thank you for the answer.